# polynomial relations between modular functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables

$\newcommand{\Qbar}{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$
We define a modular function to be a meromorphic modular form of weight 0 for some subgroup (not necessarily congruence) $\Gamma\le\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which is holomorphic on the upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$. Let $f$ be a modular function for $\Gamma$, and suppose $f$ is not a modular function for any larger subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

We may assume that $f$ is integral over $\Qbar[j]$, in which case by  [Does a modular function primitive for $\Gamma$ generate the function field of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220946/does-a-modular-function-primitive-for-gamma-generate-the-function-field-of) , its monic minimal polynomial has degree equal to $n := [\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}):\pm\Gamma]$.

The extension $\Qbar[j][f]$ over $\Qbar[j]$ is in general not etale. This is bad for me if the branch locus contains points where $j$ is not an algebraic integer, so I'm interested in using $f$ to construct other modular functions $f'$ such that $\Qbar[j][f']$ is branched only above algebraic integers on the $j$-line. I will say that a modular function $f$ is only branched over algebraic integers if $\Qbar[j][f]$ is only branched above algebraic integers on the $j$-line.

Now fix an $f$ a modular function for $\Gamma$ as above.

**Question 1:** Does there exist a $\gamma\in\text{GL}_2^+(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $f(\gamma z)$ (as a modular function for $\Gamma\cap\Gamma(N)$ for some $N$) is only branched above algebraic integers?

**Question 2:** Do there exist congruence modular functions $g,h$ such that $gf+h$ is only branched above algebraic integers?

**Question 3:** Does there exist a congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0$ such that if $\Qbar[\Gamma_0]$ denotes the affine ring of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma_0$, then $\Qbar[\Gamma_0][f]$ is unramified over $\Qbar[\Gamma_0]$ away from the preimages of $j = 0,1728$?

I sort of have no intuition for this - In part this is just a commutative algebra question - what options are there for "twisting" $f$ into some $f'$ so that the discriminant of the minimal polynomial for $f'$, as a polynomial in $j$, has only algebraic integer roots?

Comment: I wonder what has the tag "fa.functional-analysis" to do with this question?